# how to install python 3 on OS X

Tags: python, python-3.x

After I downloaded python 3 from python.org and installed it, I typed "python" on bash and still got "Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 22 2015, ...).

How can I make python 3 the default, and is changing the default necessary to develop a Django application using python 3?

Comment: Type `python3`. You're accessing the system python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `pyenv` for this.

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.5.0
pyenv global 3.5.0
```